# Failed to assign a string value from StringStream.str() into a String variable

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have being trying to compare 2 strings in below code. 1 is generated from boost::filesystem::path object.

```
bool CommLibManager::Initialize() {
    std::string cPath = xstr(CS_RUN_PREFIX);
    cPath += "/bin/";
    filesystem::path currPath = filesystem::path(cPath);
    filesystem::directory_iterator it(currPath);

    for (; it != filesystem::directory_iterator(); it++) {
        filesystem::path path = (*it).path();

        // avoid non shared libraries & non comm libs
        // @ubuntuPort: update compare() method call into std::string compatible boost::path::compare methods. 
        //if ((path.extension() != ".so") || ((path.filename().compare(0, 7, "libcscl")) != 0)) {


        std::stringstream strStream;
        std::string pathString;
        std::string filePattern = "libcscl";
        strStream << path.filename();

        //pathString = strStream.str();
        pathString.assign(strStream.str());

        std::cout << "File name: " << pathString << "Extension: " << path.extension() <<endl;
        if ((path.extension() != ".so") || (filePattern.compare(0, 7, pathString) != 0)) {   


        //if ((path.extension() != ".so") || (path.filename() != (filesystem::path)"libcscl")) {   
            //@ubuntuPort: Debug
            merr("@ubuntuPort: Debug");
            continue;
        }

        // Some code here.

        return true;
}
```

I cannot compile the source with above code because of `pathString.assign(strStream.str());` line. it is giving below error:

```
src/mgr.cpp: In member function ‘bool CommLibManager::Initialize()’:
src/mgr.cpp:41:37: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
```

I can't understand the reason, Please help.

Comment: Which line is line 41?  What are the includes for this file?

Comment: @Ninja: It is `pathString.assign(strStream.str());`

Comment: Ok, so where is column 37 in that line in your source file?  Is it between the parenthesis?  What about the includes?  I would guess you're missing one and one of the other includes provides partial information for the classes involved, but not as much as a full include would.  Did the commented out line above it work?

Comment: Column 37 is starting from `.str()`, Same error is generated for the commented line. I will update to add include list also.

Comment: Well, [this](http://ideone.com/xlv7bw) works fine.  I suggest you create a short compilable example of the problem.

Comment: Seems like preprocessor problem. Make preprocessed output and check the line containing 'pathString.assign'.

Comment: @9dan and @Ninja: Finally I replace stringstream to string conversion by converting boost filesystem::path to string(`std::string pathString = path.filename().string();`). Now it is working.